# how to keep selected value in dropdown after submit in php

Tags: php

I am using values from a database to be populated in a select input box in php however, when i click submit button, the the previously selected value dissapears and only the default value appears.

I have already tried some of the posts shared by other developers but mine can't seem to work.

```
  <select name="pickup">

  echo "<option value='area'>Select where you want the cab to pick you from</option>";

   <?php $sql1 = "SELECT area FROM places ORDER BY area ASC;";
   $resultSet1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

    while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet1)) {

    $area1 = $rows1['area'];

  echo "<option value='$area1'>$area1</option>";


   }?>
```

I don't get any errors, it just don't retain the previously selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippets, might solve your query -

```
<?php
@session_start(); /*This line would be on top of the page*/
    if(isset($_POST["demo"]))  {
        $_SESSION["selected_val"] = $_POST["demo"];
    }else{
        $_SESSION["selected_val"] = ""; 
    }

    echo "<select name="demo" > <option value='area'>Select where you want the cab to pick you from</option>";

    $sql1 = "SELECT area FROM places ORDER BY area ASC;";
    $resultSet1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

    while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet1)) {
        $area1 = $rows1['area'];
        $selected = ($area1 == $_SESSION["selected_val"]) ? 'selected' : "" ;
        echo "<option value='$area1' ".$selected.">$area1</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";    
?>
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors?

Comment: This answer is a mix of PHP and HTML. How is this going to work?

Answer (score 0):

Set selected Option Value in Session and After reload match option and session value and set select